# Link subdomain to digital ocean server

Tags: domain-name-system

My website (landing page for node.js app) runs on a shared hosting, I also have the node.js app running on a DigitalOcean Droplet (Ubuntu).

I want to run my website (landing page on shared hosting) on visualizr.be but when surfing to play.visualizr.be my node app (let's say IP is 192.168.0.10) needs to be showed.

This is the DNS Management screen of my shared hosting provider:
[DNS Management of the shared hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw8Ki.jpg)

The DigitalOcean domain servers are

ns1.digitalocean.com, ns2.digitalocean.com, ns3.digitalocean.com

What do I need to edit to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the record for `play.visualizr.be` to the DO IP address (192.168.0.10) and configure that to actually listen to that hostname.

NB: Your TTL is set to 4h, so it might take at least that long for the record to propagate.